# In Google's Quantum Supremacy experiment, what if we use $\theta=45°$ for two-qubit $f_{sim}$ gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-advantage, google-sycamore

In Google's Quantum Supremacy experiment, they use $f_{sim}$(fermionic-simulation) gates with $\theta=90°$ and $\phi=30°$ as their two-qubit gates. What if we use $\theta=45°$ for the two-qubit $f_{sim}$ gates? What will it do to the experiment's complexity?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please provide a link to a paper you refer to?

Answer (score 2):

I asked Sergio Boxio about this and he noted that this is discussed in the [supplementary information of the Supremacy paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11333). In particular, Figure S47 has a plot of the speedup you get due to imbalance in the Schmidt coefficients as the rotation angle drifts:

[image]

and equations 103, 104, and 105 show how to compute the relevant coefficients:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think Schmidt coefficients may be the key point to the consideration of different theta as you mentioned, and I didn't notice this before.